# Add accept rate to user profile and filter unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, unanswered-questions, accept-rate

1. I think the accept rate stat really should go on a user's profile; that's where it belongs. It can currently be seen only with question, but there is no way to quickly look it up, both for you and for other users. *(Yes, I know this suggestion is a duplicate of other ones, but they didn't get any definite answer; this is the reason I'm asking again.)*
2. When you have lots of questions in your history, finding ones that didn't receive an answer, or ones that received them but where you didn't accept one, can be difficult. A filtering option would be really helpful here.

Real use case: today I was looking at my accept rate and wanted to clean it up a little; I had to manually look for old unanswered questions, and then go back to any question of mine in order to monitor accept rate.

Comment: I'd raise it, but I have difficulties finding unanswered questions.